# Is routing between distinct wireless networks possible

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, routing, gateway

I have an existing Verizon Actiontec Router.(192.168.1.1 wireless network) and it is wired via phone line dsl to the internet. It has a unique ssid and wpa2.

I want to route local wireless client traffic to the Verizon actiontec internet router from a new Linksys wrt3200 located on another floor. There are no wire connections between the two routers. The wrt3200 is addressed as 192.168.7.1. Its own dhcp is set to provide addrs at 192.168.7.100 to its clients.

Note. I do don have experience with wireless routing. Is this typically done between separate networks?  Is there a problem with the Linksys in this regard. At one point a Linksys rep rep said I could set the wrt3200 for a wireless connection type of dhcp. But that does not work and there is no provision for specifying the actiontec ssid anyway. So I don’t know how that would have worked. I do not want to use a wireless bridge mode but want the Linksys clients on their own network. Would a different router provide what I want to do?

I don’t know how to do this. I don’t want to use bridge or extender modes. Everything works but there is no connection between routers so internet access fails of course. Please help.

Comment: Note. I do don have experience with wireless routing. Is this typically done between separate networks?  Is there a problem with the Linksys in this regard. At one point a Linksys rep rep said I could c

Comment: Have a look at the devices and whenever or not they support [WDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Distribution_System). Otherwise it depends on what their interfaces offer and what kind of access you have to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will either be impossible (likely) or very difficult without additional equipment.

The first issue you will have is that a wireless router interface can be an AP or AP client, but not both. You would need both for a routed solution (or put another AP back to back with the wrt3200 - one in AP, one in AP client connected with Ethernet)

If your wrt3200 router supports repeater mode you may be able to disable all it's routing functionality and have it bridge to the Action router. This mode is very inefficient.

A third possibility (unlikely but depends on your equipment functionality) if you have custom firmware on your wrt3200 and if it's dual band, you could possibly configure one band as an AP and the other as an AP client and route between the Interfaces. This will, however, limit the ability of clients to connect on 1 band.

Comment: Finally realizing that ‘wireless’ networks/routers can’t route as wired routers can. I have concluded as II see in your point another Ap would be wired.

Comment: I will try Power-line connectors , connecting the routers via house wiring. An old link refers to general configuration - https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/setup-a-second-wireless-router-on-your-home-network/      Thanks for your comments.